# Temperature sensor : MCP9808 - Raspberry PI

Tags: sensors, temperature

I try to plug 2 MCP9808 Temperature sensor on my Raspberry PI, but I think that it's not without a GPIO Expander, right ?

Only one MCP9808 is not a problem, but 2 is impossible without an GPIO expansion ?

https://learn.adafruit.com/mcp9808-temperature-sensor-python-library/hardware

Thanks for your answers !!

Comment: (1) mcp9808 has three hardware address lines, so you can put 8 such devices on the I2C bus. (2) Reference: https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/MCP9808.pdf.